# Make reCAPTCHA work on same Page(index.php)

Tags: forms, recaptcha

Hello Every one i have a form and i want to add reCAPTCHA to it.
This is my form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="headerimg">
        <a href="http://sonymobile.comule.com/"><img border="0" src="logo.png" alt="AUD Confession" width="auto" height="auto"></a>
        <div class="headertxt">Confession</div>
    </div>
    <table font-family="inherit">
        <tr><td class="comm" colspan="2">Comment: </td></tr>
        <tr><td colspan="5"><textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="50" id="comments" class="common" autofocus></textarea></td></tr>
        <tr><td><?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "6Lc1RewSAAAAAO2Emd1_ICM5qUssQdfqF0vRiCE9"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?></tr></td>
        <tr><td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="myButton" value="SUBMIT"></td></tr>
    </table> 
</form>
```

The Problem is that reCAPTCHA check it on `action="verify.php"` and show whether it is correct or not but do not submit the form values on index.php.

Codes on verify.php

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "6Lc1RewSAAAAAPBsu1AnNhJpIbS64XR0fLqEioVb";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

I want reCAPTCHA to check on the same page i:e; `action="index.php"`.
Please Help.
Or suggest something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I myself figured it out and got the solution.
All I have to do is add some codes in the place of 
`// Your code here to handle a successful verification`
 The php codes that insert User Data into database.